# Audio not working Ubuntu 15.04 and Acer ES1-311

Tags: sound, acer

Here is my audio device:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
```

In alsamixer everything is 100 and unmuted. There's also an option called 'Auto-Mute' which I disabled.

Running this command produces no sound:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

ALSA seems to detect the card:

```
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

More info:

```
# lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0938
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 95
    Memory at 90800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

In pavucontrol it shows input from the microphone but not from the output speaker (you know the bars that fill up to show activity).

Now as well I've run:

```
alsa force-reload
apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And now there is no audio applet and the sound window is transparent.

[Transparent sound window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BVKE.png)

What else can I do? Can anyone please point me in the right direction, or somewhere I can find more info? If I reinstall Ubuntu, it doesn't fix the problem.